# Having trouble with making lots of spells in a game

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm having trouble with figuring out a way to implement spells in my game. The problem is that I want to add many spells that are different(like teleportation, telekinesis, fire control etc.). The first thing I tried was making a big class hierarchy like :

```
Spell -> Passive ->Speed
                 ->Flying

      -> Active ->Teleportation
                  Telekinesis
```

At the start it seemed good but when I started implementing a lot of spells it started to get messy.

I've searched for other solution and I found about the Entity-Component based system. But I don't think it'll be a good solution.
So do any of you know of any other approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you used something like the [`Strategy Design Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and you where to have an interface which defines an method such as `ApplySpell()` and maybe a `Name` property and the *concrete* spell implemented said interface?

That way, for each character, you could iterate over their assigned spells and use the `Name` property to get the name (maybe you want to list them through a UI or something like that), or maybe store them in a dictionary where the name of the spell is the key, and the actual spell implementation is the value.

What you could do then is that once that the user has selected the spell, all that you need to do is to call `ApplySpell()` and what the actual spell does is delegated to the class which represents the spell.

In this way, you would not need to worry which spell you need to invoke because everything is being done behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm agree with your solution, but C# is not java and I think "string SpellName { get; }" fits better.

Comment: By the way, we are in a Spell interface, so "SpellName" is redundant. Finally "string Name { get; }" is sufficient.

Comment: @Orace: I see what you mean and completely agree. Amended.

Comment: nice work :o) I did not notice first that the function name is "ApplySpell" with a redundancy too. This name makes your explanation easier to understand but badly make the code heavier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is ok, but for properties you can use interfaces or base classes as properties:

```
class SpellBase
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; } // all spells have to have name
    public virtual void Animate() { ... } // abstract?
    ...
}
```

Then for teleportation

```
class TeleportationSpell: SpellBase, IEffect
{
   ... // set name, override Animate() and implement IAreaEffect (as OnSelfEffect() for teleport)
}

interface IEffect
{
    public EffectBase Effect {get; set;}
    ...
}

class EffectBase { ... }

class OnSelfEffect: EffectBase { ... }
class OnTargetEffect: EffectBase { ... }
class OnSelfAndTargetEffect: EffectBase { ... }
```

Interfaces will make your hierarchy less branchy, but will required more code to implement (which is not really a problem, as you can move common code into methods and call them).

Answer (score 1):

The Entity-Component approch is a good solution for your problem. :)
You should invest more time in understanding it.

You always have to make a decision between "is a" or "have a" relationship.
Where "is a" means inheritance and "have a" means composition.

The thing on EntityComponents is to put every game object attribute into a component class and then just put these components together. You could create every combination of properties without or less code changes (depending on the implementation).
With using that approch it's also easy to create a multiplayer game, because you have just a few places in your code to put the communication stuff.

The other side is you will have a lot of classes and everything is highly decoupled. In general that's a plus and what we want as OO developers.
But for a new developer or a developer with not that high skills, this could be horrible to read.

So i would advise you to choose the entity component approach, because your game will be easier to extend in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple classes for each type of magic, just start casing them all in one Magic class and handle them from there as per a trigger?

```
switch(castID) {
default:
    break;
case 1: //air strike
    Spell AirStrike = new Spell('AirStrike');
    break;
case 2:
    ...
}
```

And then have a class for Spell and handle each spell in there based on params sent